# How to swich current view with vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am still trying to find easy wat to switch view depending on user action (click on menu item for example). I read docs and look like I can do it with [Dynamic_Components](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Dynamic_Components) So I wrote next code: and I can't understand why I do not see nothing. What do I miss?

```
  var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
        template: `
              <p>Guest</p>
            `});

   var UserMenu = Vue.extend({
        template: `
                <p>User</p>
            `});

Vue.component('guestmenu', GuestMenu);
Vue.component('usermenu', UserMenu);

var App = Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data:
    {
      currentView: 'guestmenu'
    }
  })

App.currentView: 'guestmenu'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjyr0g8j/

Comment: `App.currentView: 'guestmenu'` should be `App.currentView = 'guestmenu'`

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually load vue.js somewhere.
2. App.currentView **=** 'guestmenu'.
3. Vue is a constructor, you need to call it with `new`. It even yells at you if you forget: `[Vue warn]: Vue is a constructor and should be called with the 'new' keyword`
4. Never mount to  or . This is also a console warning!

```js
  var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
        template: `
              <p>Guest</p>
            `});

   var UserMenu = Vue.extend({
        template: `
                <p>User</p>
            `});
            
Vue.component('guestmenu', GuestMenu);
Vue.component('usermenu', UserMenu);

var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:
    {
      currentView: 'guestmenu'
    }
  })

App.currentView = 'usermenu'
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component :is="currentView"> </component>
</div>
```